# error: package org.apache.log4j does not exist while running code from cmd

Tags: java, maven, cmd, log4j

While running `javac Main.java` command I get a `package org.apache.log4j does not exist` error.

`Main` class

```
public class Main {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        logger.info("in Main class");
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
        xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

`log4j.properties`

```
log4j.rootCategory=debug,console
log4j.logger.com.demo.package=debug,console
log4j.additivity.com.demo.package=false

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.immediateFlush=true
log4j.appender.console.encoding=UTF-8

log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.conversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n
```

Error message I get is:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Assumption 1 (wrong): no imports posted in the source class → imports have to be added

Looks that you're missing `import` statements in your `Main` class. 
Try this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.BasicConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();

        logger.info("in Main class");
    }
}
```

### Real problem (after I fixed the image display in the post)

You're running the compilation not with maven buth with command-line `javac`. Without maven, you don't have dependencies automatically added to your classpath.

#### If you want to run from command line

In this case, you have to add log4j to your classpath. 
It will look like this (running from sources directory, which is `<project_root>\src\main\java` in the default maven layout:

`javac company/Main.java -cp %userprofile%\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17\log4j-1.2.17.jar`

I assume that your local Maven repo is in default Windows path `%userprofile%\.m2`. If it is in some other part (or Linux), you have to change the path to your `log4j-1.2.17.jar`.

In this case, the class `Main.class` will be compiled into the same package where `Main.class` is.

#### If  you want to compile with maven

Just run `mvn compile` from the directory where your `pom.xml` is.
Note that maven will compile classes into the `target` directory, i.e. your compiled class will be in path like `\target\classes\company\Main.class` (relative to your project root, where your `pom.xml` is).

Comment: I have imports in my class

Comment: Ok, sorry, can you please post your project to github then?

Comment: @kateswerg I finally understood your problem. You're running your project not with maven, but with cmd `javac`. It will require to add log4j into your classpath. I will update the answer shortly.

Comment: I added LOG4J_HOME C:\Program Files\log4j-1.2.17.jar.zip to environment variables and the same directory to Path variable. 
It doesn't help.

Comment: @kateswerg I've updated the answer, please check and try.

Comment: @kateswerg you're welcome. Can you then accept my answer, please?